# Binding function to another function in object

Tags: javascript, oop, function

I try to bind a function but I dont really know how its work
For example

```
   q={};
   q.e=function(){return 1;}
   q.e.i=function(){alert(this);}
   q.e().i(); //Nothing happend I excepted that it will alert 1
```

So how does it work?

Thank you.

Comment: Wild function binding will not achieve anthing. Do you what to understand the binding or are you trying to solve a specific issue?

Comment: You should be getting an error when calling `q.e().i();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting an error when calling `q.e().i();` `q.e() == 1` so `(1).i()` is an error since the Number object doesn't have an `i` method.

Hard to help since the code doesn't make any sense. I can only say that what you expected doesn't make sense in my head :)

Here's some code that would do what you expect

```
var q = {};
q.e = function() { return 1; };

q.e.i = function() { alert(this); }

// Call q.e.i, specifying what to use as this
q.e.i.call(q.e());
```

The trick is that in JS, `this` changes depending on how you call the function.

```
function a() {
  console.log(this);
}

var obj = {
   method: a
};

// Outputs the window object, calling a function without a `.` passes    
// The window object as `this`
a();
// Outputs the obj, when you say obj.method(), method is called with obj as `this`
obj.method();
// You can also force the this parameter (to the number 1 in this case)
// outputs 1
obj.method.call(1);
```

Comment: this is code in ebay how does it work then?
vjo.ctype("vjo.darwin.domain.jaguar.page.PageEventHandler").protos({constructs:function(_1,_2,_3,_4){this.scope=_1;this.elem=_2;this.type=_3;this.func=_4}

Comment: @user1801625 That sounds like a different question. They're using some framework, I don't see the resemblance to what you asked. That code looks like it's creating a class giving it a constructor

Comment: Why?its and object that has method that return to another method no?

Answer (score 2):

A function does also *inherit* from *Object* in Javascript. Hence you can assign *properties* to a *function object*, which you're just doing by calling

```
q.e.i = function() {};
```

but thats it. If you want to call it, you need to the same semantics

```
q.e.i();
```

in your current snippet, you're trying to execute `.i()` on the *return value* of `e()`, which happens to be the number `1`.

Comment: `q.e()` does return 1, but it won't have a method i when calling `q.e().i()`

Comment: @JuanMendes: oh you're right about the return value, updating that.